# Is there a way to repartition the input topic in Kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topic keyed by byte[], I want to repartition it and process the topic by another key in a field in the message body.

I find there is `KGroupedStream` and `groupby` function. But it asks for an aggregation function to convert to a KTable/KStream. I don't need an aggregate. I just want to repartition and process the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Kafka Streams 2.5.x or older)

Not sure if this is entirely kosher, but it works and the repartition topic is created automatically and with the right number of partitions wrt the `stream`.

```
KTable emptyTable = someTable.filter((k, v) -> false);
KStream stream = ...
KStream repartionedStream = stream.selectKey(...)
                            .leftJoin(emptyTable, (v, Null) -> v, ...);
```

**Edit**

This approach apparently became a complicated  abomination deserving of an avalanche of downvotes and a flogging in Aug 2020 when Kafka Streams 2.6.0 was introduced and KStream.repartition() came into existence.

So for streams version **2.6.x+** you must use

```
KStream stream = ...
KStream repartionedStream = stream.selectKey(...)
                                  .repartition();
```

Comment: This solution seems rather complicated... Why would you use "dummy left-join"? You can just use `repartition()`... (or `through()` in order versions; `through()` requires you to create the used topic manually though...)

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I don't think two lines of code gets into "complicated" territory. This was the state of affairs in 2019 when I gave the answer. For your approach I would have to travel in time to late 2020 when streams 2.6 was released with the repartition() in KStream.

Comment: Fair enough... My comment about "complicated" was not about "two lines of code" in particular, but that it's not clear what the code does, and that you need to add a table, what also makes processing more expensive... Overall, a quite complex workaround. Even if `repartition()` was added only later, there is `through()` that should be used instead.

Comment: `through()` didn't do what the OP needed that's why my answer was accepted. It doesn't create a topic with the right number of partitions automatically. Incidentally, it didn't do it for me either and hence the solution, as strange as it may be. The whole argument about complication does not seem relevant unless there is a comparable solution pre v2.6. Using `through()` is not.

Comment: The question does not say anything about topic auto-creation...

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can. You set a new key and afterwards pipe the data through another topic.

```java
// repartition() will create the required topic automatically for your,
// with the same number of partitions as your input topic;
//
// it's also possible to set the number of partitions explicitly to scale in/out
// via `repartitioned(Repartitioned.numberOfPartitions(...))`
KStream stream = ...
KStream repartionedStream = stream.selectKey(...)
                                  .repartition();

// older versions:
//
// using `through()` you need to create the use topic manually,
// before you start your application
KStream stream = ...
KStream repartionedStream = stream.selectKey(...)
                                  .through("topic-name");
```

Note, that you need to create the topic you use in `through()` before you start the application with the desired number of partitions.

Comment: if I don't use through(), I assume a topic is created automatically, right?

Comment: Depends. Auto-repartitioning happens "on demand" only, thus, only if there is a key-dependent operation like `groupBy()` or `join()` after `.selectKey()`.

Comment: I don't need to materialize the new topic in my case. I only want to generate output, which is a RPC call to an external service for a message based on the new partition. As I understand, I don't need to create a new topic or rely on an intermediate topic, so no need to call through, right?

Comment: Not entirely sure if I understand. If you want to do the RPC from your Streams application, you will need to call `through()` and do the RPC afterwards.

Comment: .selectKey() already does repartitioning, so there's no need for a .repartition()

Comment: That's not 100% current. `selectKey()` only "marks the stream for repartitioning" -- if you don't have a downstream join/groupBy, no repartitioning happens.

Answer (score 1):

There's a method repartition() on the KStream interface that allows you to repartition the topic, based on Serdes and a StreamPartitioner, instead of mapping/selectingKey() plus applying a through or repartition.