# Kafka streams repartitioning

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In Kafka streams when function to modify the key is used then Kafka Streams creates internal repartitioned topic. I wonder what is number of partition of newly created topic? When new topic partition number is grater than 1 then other consumers from consumers group also are involved for consuming that internal topic?

I am trying to scale one of my consumers but I try to understand first how does it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't set it using `Repartitioned.numberOfPartitions()`, then it's the same as the input topic.

Reference - [Is there a way to repartition the input topic in Kafka streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49578931/2308683)

Comment: Thanks, do you know if then this re-partitioned topic is consumed by whole consumer group?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? You cannot assign consumers in Streams API to any less than all partitions of topics

Comment: My dilemmas arise from the fact that a given consumer subscribe to some specific topics, and I don't know any mechanism in Kafka to let other consumers know that they need to subscribe to a new internal topic. There is group leader and group coordinator but their responsibilities are different.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You should never manually subscribe to internal `repartition` topics. You'd create a separate topic with `through` or `to`, as the link refers to. Still, Kafka Streams reading from those topics will always read all partitions